# CSS How to animate a transition from opacity 0 upon hover

Tags: html, css

I want to create a transition effect when the submenu list is visible upon hovering on the parent element.

This is the list in html:

```
<ul id="main">
<li>a
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Ideally there would be a transition effect from opacity: 0 to opacity:0.9, yet I still haven't managed to do so.

```
#main li ul {
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;  
}
#main li:hover > ul {
   display: block;
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 0.9;
}
```

JSfiddle link, with a snippet of my css for the list too.
http://jsfiddle.net/r66yyhhv/5/

Comment: remove display:none;

Comment: @user3365721 wow thanks! That's so obvious, stupid me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the display, and visibility properties.

([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zo8qrj4b/))

```
#main li ul {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;  
}
#main li:hover > ul {
   opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the display properties, but leave the visibility properties.  Otherwise the sub-list will still trigger the hover.

Here is an example with more modular code and a nice slide down effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/eq772a1v/

```
.with-dropdown-list {
  position: relative;
}

.with-dropdown-list ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}

.with-dropdown-list:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: .9;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Comment: Love it when people downvote without a comment. I'd love to hear why this was downvoted when it's clearly correct.